# Can't run android applications

Tags: android

I have a helloworld android application. But it can't run.

(Same code ran well yesterday. I don't know what configuration I changed..)

When I pressed "run as android application" in eclipse, nothing happened.

I used command line to run it:
`$adb install -rv HelloAndroid.apk`
But nothing happened, either.

I can see my emulator from `$adb devices`

```
List of devices attached 
emulator-5554   device
```

How can I find the problem?

Answer (score 0):

try running these commands:

```
$adb kill-server
$adb start-server
```

and then retry. For some reason Eclipse has a hard time running the apks if the server is started before the emulator.